# How to get NSToolbar Height?

Tags: swift, macos, nstoolbar

How do I know NSToolbar height? When I place a NSView inside a NSWindow with a NSToolbar on, how do I set the height of the NSView so it can take all available height in the window?

Answer (score 3):

In macOS 11 or newer, you can make use of `safeAreaInsets` to determine the height of the toolbar in case you have enabled setting 'Full Size Content View':

```
guard let contentView = window?.contentView else {
    return
}

let toolbarHeight = contentView.safeAreaInsets.top
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set/replace the `contentView` of the window, the window will automatically and necessarily resize it to the right size (or resize itself if the view's size is constrained with greater priority than `NSLayoutConstraint.Priority.windowSizeStayPut`).

If you're putting your view within the provided content view, then the content view's `bounds` indicates the rectangle within which your view will be placed.

If you just want the content rect of the window, you can get that with `window.contentRect(forFrameRect:window.frame)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you don't need to account for the toolbar height; the runtime does that for you automatically.  Just add the view as you ordinarily would.  Programmatically it would look like this:

```
let view = CustomView( frame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, _wndW, _wndH) )       
 window.contentView!.addSubview (view)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used window.setFrame() to change window size, while I should have used window.setContentSize().

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
let toolbarHeight = window.frame.height - (window.contentView?.bounds.height ?? .zero)
```